# Can't get the keyPressed function to detect the keys pressed

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to write my first game, a snake game, but I'm really stuck. I have no clue why this isn't working. I'm at the stage where I'm trying to move the snake with the arrow keys. But it doesn't work! I'm using the p5.js webeditor. https://editor.p5js.org/

This is what I got so far!

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800);
    snakeX = 0
    snakeY = 0
    snakeXspeed = 1
    snakeYspeed = 0
}

function keyPressed(){
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW){
      snakeYspeed = -1
      snakeXspeed = 0
    } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW){
      snakeYspeed = 0
      snakeXspeed = -1
    } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW){
      snakeYspeed = 1
      snakeXspeed = 0
    } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW){
      snakeYspeed = 0
      snakeXspeed = 1
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(0);

    fill(255);
    rect(snakeX, snakeY, 20, 20);

    snakeX = snakeX + snakeXspeed
    snakeY = snakeY + snakeYspeed
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: From what learned, the keyPressed function is being called everytime you press a key. https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed

Comment: Event was a new thing to me. Have to look it up!

Comment: Can you pleas explain, what does not work? Please note the focus has to be at the canvas. (Click on the canvas, then the keys are recognised)

Comment: Oh that's why! I had to click on the canvas! Thanks! It works now!